# Snowflake: AWS IAM Role for notification integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, identity-management

I am trying to create **multiple notification integrations** in Snowflake. As per my knowledge, I will have to create a new role per notification integration as a different `SF_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID` is generated for each notification.

Is my understanding correct or do we have a way to utilize one role for all integrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to list the snowflake external id in the policy like below, I have storage and notification integration using same policy.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "${snowflake_storage_integration.integration.storage_aws_iam_user_arn}"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "sts:ExternalId": [
                    "${snowflake_storage_integration.integration.storage_aws_external_id}",
                    "${snowflake_notification_integration.integration.aws_sns_external_id}"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

See the aws doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-logic-multiple-context-keys-or-values.html